# View Oracle GeoRaster in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-spatial

I have imported SRTM DEM into Oracle 11g using FME.The block size is set to 128X128.I am able to view the data in QGIS,Tatuk and play with it using GDAl command line.Unable to view the same in ArcMap. Never.Never faced any issue with vector though.Why Raster loading is not as simple as vector ? Apparently , all documentation that I have come across has evasive responses providing no clue at all on what to do in simple steps.

ArcCatalog shows me The raster and RDT tables.I get the error "The specified raster column does not exist", when try to drag and drop.I have verified that my DBTUNE parameters are set SDO_GEORASTER.

Any clues?

Comment: Hello, did you ever found a solution? I'm experiencing similar problems.

Comment: Sorry,did not find a solution.ESRI is non committal on solution on work around